# Is it possible to download GAE datastore from appcfg.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to download datastore records from a project:

```
appcfg.py --application=id --url=http://id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api download_data foobar --filename=foobar.bak
```

It completes with a message like:

```
[INFO    ] Have 1 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 1 entities (3715 bytes) transferred in 3.8 seconds
```

But when I examine the resulting sqlite3 there is nothing in it resembling the data in the datastore entity. What am I missing?

[gcloud info](http://s.natalian.org/2016-02-29/info.txt)

I am aware of the backup to cloud storage method, but that seems far too cumbersome for my liking. Perhaps someone has written some simple JSON exporter?

Comment: The data is stored in sqlite as serialized protocol buffers; you can't query it directly, you have to go through your app running locally.

Comment: But download_data only seems to download one "table" at a time. How do I get all "kinds" of data so my app can run locally with `dev_appserver.py` for example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can choose which kinds to download with the `--kind` argument to appcfg.py.

Comment: But I want all kinds. It seems to do only one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why you have 'foobar' after 'download_data'.

This should work to download all kinds:

```
appcfg.py --application=id --url=http://id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api download_data --filename=foobar.bak
```

Don't forgot that you have to upload it to your devserver before using it locally:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url http://localhost:8080/remote_api --file=foobar.bak --application=id
```

By default you will get everything. If you want to *restrict* it to a particular namespace or kind, you can add:

```
--namespace="your_namespace"
```

or

```
--kind="kind"
```

Comment: Don't quite understand why I have to upload before downloading? Assume I have a whole bunch of customer data already on the GAE cloud that I need to work with locally for a new feature.

Comment: You don't. You download to your local machine, this download doesn't 'load' it into your local devserver though, it's just a random file. One you have this, you can then 'upload it' to your locally running instance, which is really just having your local one read it so it can be used locally. Again, the path is GAE Cloud --Download--> Your HDD as a File --Upload--> Your local devserver instance